# Resize Images crossplattform with node.js

Tags: image, node.js, image-processing, node-webkit

I wrote a little tool with node-webkit. One reason I chose node-webkit is the fact that it is easy to distribute your app to all major plattforms.

Something I would love to do now, is to resize a bunch of images located on the file storage.

I found plenty of packages which do this via ImageMagick. This would require the user to have ImageMagick installed, which is bad...

Using a webservice is no option. There can easily be around 600 images.

If there is no solution, I will only run that task IF imagemagick is installed.

Comment: I am not sure, but this may work: https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas/blob/master/examples/resize.js

Comment: This uses Cairo BUT since Cairo has binaries for all relevant platforms, this might be an option. Thank you (:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the canvas tag to resize your image.

Load the image in a canvas with the new size:

```
...
var tempCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
tempCanvas.width = newWidth;
tempCanvas.height = newHeight;
var ctx = tempCanvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.src = imageSrc;
img.onload = function () {
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
};
```

Get resized image back from canvas:

```
...
var image = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
image = image.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
var buffer = new Buffer(image, 'base64');
fs.writeFile('filename.png', buffer, function (error) {
  if (error) {
    // TODO handle error
  }
});
...
```

In this example the resulting image will be a png. You can use as result type whatever node-webkit supports. If you have different image types as input and want to output in the same type you need to add some code that sets the correct mime type to `canvas.toDataURL`.

Comment: Note that imageSrc can be a local file, but you need to use a file URI. e.g. 'file://Users/me/Pictures/image.jpg'

Answer (score 0):

I am developing an image processing module without any runtime dependencies; which means your users don't need to have imagemagick installed. It's still at early stages, but already usable.

Part of the module is written in C++, so you'll have to make sure to `npm install` the module on each platform you package your app (better than telling your users to pre-install imagemagick, imho). node-webkit apps are distributed per-platform anyway, so it shouldn't be a problem. Note, though, that I haven't yet tested it with node-webkit,

With this module, resizing an image is as simple as:

```
image.batch().resize(200, 200).writeFile('output.jpg',function(err){
    // done
});
```

More info at the module's [Github repo](https://github.com/EyalAr/lwip).